# How to install Tensorflow Object Detection API offline

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, object-detection, object-detection-api

I want to install the Tensorflow object detection api on a machine without internet connection.

What I have done so far:

- Creating a virtual environment with pip
- Install Tensorflow
- Create Requirements.txt 'pip freeze > requirements.txt'
- Download all required wheel files with `pip download -r requirements.txt`
- Moving the requirements.txt and the wheels files to another dictionary
- Changing directory to Tensorflow/models/research
- `pip install .`  (already used protbuf to create python files)
- Create Requirements.txt 'pip freeze > requirements.txt'
- Download all required wheel files with `pip download -r requirements.txt`
- Moving the requirements.txt and the wheels files to another dictionary

Now I am on the offline machine:

- Python is installed
- Creating a new environment
- Install Tensorflow from the dictionaries I created before (requirements.txt and wheel files) with `pip install -r requirementx.txt --no-index -f .\`
- Installation completed without error
- Install Tensorflow Object Detection API from the dictionaries I created before (requirements.txt and wheel files) `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index -f .\`

Now I get several errors:
“Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement”
It seems that pip still wants to download some packages (Some are as wheel in the folder, some not).

However downloading the missing wheels results in new missing wheels.

How can I download or build all necessary packages to use the Obj Detection API offline?

Comment: Are there any differences between the two machines (like python version, or large OS differences)? Also, you could install tensorflow and Object Detection API and create one requirements.txt file.

Comment: No, there are no Differences: I use Python 3.8.9 on Windows 10. I have also tried to create one requirements, but there I have the same problems.

Comment: One problem is that some packages are no wheel files but tar.gz, which cannot be build/opened/installed.

Comment: Then the second environment does not have the required build tools installed. https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-pip-setuptools-and-wheel-are-up-to-date

Comment: Assuming both machines share Python of the same version, bitness and ABI: on the first machine, go through downloaded dists and issue `pip wheel pkg-ver.tar.gz` for each source dist; this will produce the missing wheels.

Comment: @hoefling It was a combination of several problems. The requirements.txt did not contain all necessary packages. During the installation some of the packages necessary to build the package (e.g. wheel) could not be found, since they will be installed later following the requirements.txt order. Installing wheel and some other packages beforehand solved the problem.